# Any way to modify Trello cover image so it is on the side (like Evernote)?

Tags: trello

Is it possible to move the Trello cover image to the side of card title (like Evernote)? Simply because it is more useful to organize some projects when pictures are on the side of the card. Also it allows more vertical cards to be displayed at one time.

I'm sure it is possible with a hack (I've seen Chrome extension to shorten the width of lists on Trello) and I will also suggest it to the Trello team. But how would I go about changing this now? Is there a userscript I could work on? (not very familiar with CSS or HTML myself)